# Entropy Calculation and derivation of logarithm

Tags: computer-science, information-theory, computational-mathematics

I have probabilities as 
$$p_1 = 0.4,\ p_2 = 0.3,\ p_3=0.2,\ p_4=0.1$$

hence entropy is given by:
$$H(x) = -\big(0.4\cdot \log_2(0.4) + 0.3\cdot \log_2(0.3) + 0.2\cdot \log_2(0.2) + 0.1\cdot \log_2(0.1)\big)$$

I derive this to
$$H(x) = -\big(1 - \log_2(10) + 0.3\cdot \log_2(3)\big)$$

and I am unable  to derive it further

can you please say if I just need to use calculator or it is possible to use log tricks.

Comment: So, what is your end  goal exactly? Just simplifying the expression?

Comment: End goal is to produce a scalar value, but I am thinking is it possible to do it without calculator, the way I simplified to 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take $$\begin{align}-\big(1 - \log_2(10) + 0.3\cdot \log_2(3)\big) = -\big(1 - \log_2(2\cdot 5) + 0.3\cdot \log_2(3)\big) \\  = -\big(1 - 1-\log_2(5) + 0.3\cdot \log_2(3)\big) \\ =\log_2(5)-0.3\cdot \log_2(3)\end{align}$$ I don't think there is much left you can do with this besides stick it into a calculator

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but still we have result as log

Comment: @GrigorNazaryan yes, in your post you said to "please say if I just need to use calculator or it is possible to use log tricks".  I'm telling you there is nothing else you can do algebraically to cancel the logarithm quantities. You will need a calculator to get an approximate answer, or just leave it as is for an exact answer